# Pandas edit dataframe

Tags: mongodb, pandas, dataframe, mlab

I am querying a MongoDB collection, with two queries and appending them to get a single data frame.(keys are: status, date, uniqueid)

```
for record in results:


query1 =  (record["sensordata"]["user"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(query1.items())

query2 =  (record["created_date"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(query2.items())
index = "status"
result = df1.append(df2, index)
b = result.transpose()
print b
b.to_csv(q)
```

output is :

```
        0             1                           2
0  status      uniqueid                        date
1       0  191b117fcf5c  2017-03-01 17:51:08.263000
        0             1                           2
0  status      uniqueid                        date
1       1  191b117fcf5c  2017-03-01 17:51:17.216000
        0             1                           2
0  status      uniqueid                        date
1       1  191b117fcf5c  2017-03-01 17:51:23.269000
        0             1                           2
0  status      uniqueid                        date
1       1  191b117fcf5c  2017-03-01 18:26:17.216000
        0             1                           2
0  status      uniqueid                        date
1       1  191b117fcf5c  2017-03-01 18:26:21.130000
        0             1                           2
0  status      uniqueid                        date
1       0  191b117fcf5c  2017-03-01 18:26:28.217000
```

how to remove these extra 0 ,1 ,2 and 0,1 in rows and columns?
also, i don't want status uniqueid and date repeat everytime.
My desired output should be like this:

```
 status         uniqueid                           date
     0      191b117fcf5c      2017-03-01 18:26:28.217000
     1      191b117fcf5c      2017-03-01 19:26:28.192000
     1      191b117fcf5c      2017-04-01 11:16:28.222000
```

Comment: What return `query1`?

Comment: Maybe the best is add sample `results`

Comment: Looks like some weird multi-index, can you post the output of `b.columns` and `b.index`?